# Geolocation Pricing in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Is the geolocation API free no matter how many requests are make within a month or year? I have tried searching with the open layers for pricing and there is nothing associated with Geolocation pricing. I also checked the FQA and there is nothing.

Comment: OpenLayers is just one JavaScript framework to display data. How you get the data "is your business". -- So you should find a provider (and conditions), and you just give it to OL library.

Comment: OpenLayers geolocation is simply a wrapper for JavaScript geolocation, which uses the device's location service (based on GPS and mobile signal) so is always free, but this may not be available on all devices and must be enabled by the user.  If device or browser geolocation is not enabled you would need a third party service (IP Geolocation API) to estimate location from the IP address - there are many alternatives each with different free limits and prices.